# Android: Prevent go to next activity when there's no image at ImageView

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I created an app that required a user to snap a photo and save it to the MySQL database. There are 3 buttons it that activity which is "Camera", "Save", and "Next". Currently, if there's no photo at ImageView, user can still go to the next activity if they click "Next" button.

Now, how I want to make sure that the user cannot go to the next activity if there's no image in ImageView. Below is my code:

```
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(taskClass.getPhoto_before() != null){

                Intent intent = new Intent(TaskUpdateBefore.this, TaskUpdateAfter.class);
                intent.putExtra("task", taskClass);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else{

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TaskUpdateBefore.this,"Please snap a photo and save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                TextView alert = toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                alert.setTextColor(Color.rgb(213, 56, 23));
                alert.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25);
                alert.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                alert.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                toast.show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: You should debug and check what the value of `taskClass.getPhoto_before()` is when the Next button is clicked

Comment: Before this, when the column Image format at the database is NOT NULL, there no problem. But when I change it to NULL, this problem occurred

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: How to debug? I just see on the logcat

Comment: Check this tutorial is you're using Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug.

To add a break point, click on the index left side bar (which contain line number) at the line which you want to check the value while running the app

Answer (score 0):

If you've not set any image by default the you can check something like

```
if(imageView.getDrawable!=null){
    Intent intent = new Intent(TaskUpdateBefore.this, TaskUpdateAfter.class);
    intent.putExtra("task", taskClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: the getDrawable is red in color. hm

Comment: You mean the background you've set by default is Red? if that is the case then compare it if is not RED anymore instead of null.

Comment: the word ""getDrawbale()

Comment: I have been referring to the public method of the imageView, i'm not quite following you, refer this, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable()
this might help you clear your doubt.